# MariaDB set geometry field SRID SQL error

Tags: srid, mariadb

I'm trying to update a geometry field and set its SRID using the following statement which works fine in MySQL 8 but throws the following error in mariadb 10.3.37:

```
sql error 1064 check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right 
syntax to use near `SET SRID 4326`
```

And this is the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE location_boundaries MODIFY geom GEOMETRY NOT NULL SRID 4326;
```